# How to make an Image in Flutter span the entire width of the screen while making it scroll-able

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am looking for a way to make an image span the entire width of the screen(while in landscape mode) while making the height of the image scroll-able. The images I want to render are of resolution 800*12000. What is the correct way of doing this?

I am fairly new to Flutter and Dart so easy solution will be appreciated.

Thank you

I have tried using the Image.asset() constructor inside a ListView. While it works for some Images, it throws weird error for some(Edit: Flutter no longer throws an error after updating it to v1.5.4-hotfix.2 but it still doesn't load the images sometimes ). The app just freezes when I try to load some of these images. Sometimes the image is only loaded when the device is in landscape mode

Comment: please post the error you encounter.

Comment: @George It does not print an error,(it used to but after updating flutter it doesn't anymore) the image just fails to load sometimes, while other times it works flawlessly, while other times the images load only in landscape mode.